# ACCESS DENIED to mysql DB with PHP but can login with phpmyadmin and on the command line

Tags: php, mysql, linux

**Blew away that server, restarting fresh. WAY too much time wasted on this!**

Let me know if I left any details out please. Have spent about a week researching this and trying things to no avail.

Creating a website (first time) for my upcoming wedding and I would like my guests to be able to post comments to the site. I am a professional software engineer but not a web dev so this was my attempt at teaching myself more about php and perl and learning to work with Linux.

Setup LAMP on Ubuntu 12.0.4 hosted on Amazon. Followed standard setup tutorial online. Apache2 with PHP5.

Created new MYSQL users (names changed for obvious reasons) user@localhost and user@% with passwords. All privileges granted to both (even on the specific DB), then flushed. Firewall port 3306 opened. bind-address in the mysql config file set to 0.0.0.0 or commented out (have tried both). Made sure not to start it with --skip-networking.

I can connect with user@localhost just fine when I run mysql -u user -hlocalhost -p as well as with phpmyadmin on the web. Correct privileges (including GRANT) are shown when I query that and I have granted each user full access to the DB I created for the site.

Now my issue is when using php or perl I cannot connect to the DB from the webpage or from running the scripts on the command line (such as sudo php script.php).

Here is the line of my php script that fails, I can post the perl if anyone would like:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")or die( mysql_error());
```

No matter what I do I get this error when running the script:

Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Same error, every dang time.

Now because I can log in with those same credentials through the command line and phpmyadmin I have to assume it is a setting I have messed somewhere on the server. I don't know what else to check aside from what I already have and what feels like hundreds of answers I have read on the subject haven't helped. If anyone could offer some advice that would be great, I am at wits end and about to trash the entire server and start fresh.

Or if no one has an answer for this, any other way I can achieve my end goal of having users be able to post comments to the site?

Comment: Can you please post your PHP connection code (minus real credentials) so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: Are you running Windows 7? I find that I have luck using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when I need to connect to the local machine. I believe this is because localhost on Windows 7 uses an ipv6 address.

Comment: Hmm. reasearch for a week for an acccess denied in mysql? I'd say you should call professional support now. Oracle has a phone number and there is also very good third party support like SkySQL and who else not btw.

Comment: when you say amazon do you mean AWS? is this a single EC2 instance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very personal Mysql configuration problem with not providing a concrete worklog which would allow to get enough insight. This question tries to mimic an interactive trouble-shooting session now which I believe is highly discouraged. The user is just not able to pin-point the problem in troubleshooting a configuration problem making too many words adding too little specifics.

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")or die( mysql_error());

Comment: And yes it is AWS and a single EC2 instance

Comment: hint: if phpmyadmin can connect, this is PHP code, it shows that it works. See how they do it, the code is there to read it.

Comment: I have already tried using 127.0.0.1 and no its on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Comment: How would I check what code phpmyadmin uses hakre?

Comment: and you must not run for phone support directly, there is also a long, long long listing you can use for pin-pointing access denies here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html - @user1011313: You check that by looking into the code of that software.

Comment: and try if you can connect via PDO / mysqli.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to view the code phpmyadmin uses, great suggestion I will see if it works

Comment: PDO and mysqli return the same error as well

Comment: Changing the connection string from localhost to 127.0.0.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're going to use with your scripting should have both the "@localhost" and "'@%'" - Have a peek at the man. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html  This gave me a headache once.

Comment: I setup the same user with  both localhost and %, still no luck. Ill read through that page and see if I can find something I haven't tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password")or die( mysql_error());
```

Comment: In phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php, which extension are you using, mysql or mysqli? If mysqli, you might want to try connecting with the mysqli as well in your script, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php.

Comment: I have also tried using the mysqli command for connecting, same thing :(